# Why would vncserver not use the xstartup script?

Tags: linux, fedora, vncserver, systemctl

I am using Fedora 16, and I've set up vncserver, using the systemctl method...

/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=build
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x1024
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have run:

```
systemctl --system daemon-reload
systemctl enable vncserver@:1.service
systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
```

It appeared to work fine.

Then I edited the ~build/.vnc/xstartup script. Looking in it, I see "twm" is used. I added "xhost +".

When I restarted vncserver through systemctl, the change didn't take effect. In fact, I see "twm" is not used at all, but "gnome" is, which is default on that system.

Why would the system not use the xstartup script? What is it using instead? How can I get systemctl/vncserver to use this xstartup script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that vncserver WAS using the script, but by the time it made it to the bottom, it was no longer processing lines, given the "exec" calls above it.

gnome was running, because gnome was found by the /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc script exec'ed.